# I am trying to create a formula that will return the numbers of resource that has possible duplicates and count as one along with other criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, return-value

my goal is to count the number of person that having different criteria to consider.

the below formula is working fine but not sure how are we going to put another criteria

`=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A10000<>"")/COUNTIFS(A5:A10000,A5:A10000&""))`

that formula will count duplicates as 1 but i also want to consider the date from other column

somehow like this if we are not going to consider the duplicates `=countifs(startdatecolumn, 1/1/2022,enddatecolumn, 5/3/2022)`

i tried to include that here `COUNTIFS(A5:A10000,A5:A10000&"")` like `=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A10000<>"")/COUNTIFS(A5:A10000,A5:A10000&"",startdatecolumn, 1/1/2022,enddatecolumn, 5/3/2022)` but its not working

Comment: What is your excel version? Post few sample data. Your current formula will count distinct values.

Comment: Hello @Harun24hr currently using 365. the answer of Jos works . tho im not sure how to add another criteria on that.. still trying and error how i can use it

Comment: If you are on O365 then can easily use `UNIQUE()` and `FILTER()` function then use `COUNTA()` function.

Comment: also tried to use unique and filter (which i recently discovered) but i somehow dont know how to stich it up with what i want. what i did before is show the unique values but the prob with that is it will not show the row with other dates which is very important for me as im counting the number of resource per date  like if sept 8 how many resource are there but taking account of the duplicate ones and will count as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reciprocal `SUMPRODUCT`/`COUNTIFS` is incredibly inefficient. Much better is:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A5:A10000<>"",IF(B5:B10000=DATEVALUE("1/1/2022"),IF(C5:C10000=DATEVALUE("5/3/2022"),MATCH(A5:A10000,A5:A10000,0)))),ROW(A5:A10000)-MIN(ROW(A5:A10000))+1),1))`

where I've assumed that `B5:B10000` and `C5:C10000` contain yout start and end dates respectively.

Obviously there are even more efficient set-ups if you have `O365`.

Comment: Woaaahhh.. JOS!!!! youre AWESOME... it works like magic. i tweaked some of it ofcourse based on what i need . but mate!! it works!!. but there is a problem.. haha i cant understand how it works :D as i want to add 1 or 2 more criteria and not based on date. like if that line is from specific country

Comment: Just nest additional `IF` clauses as required, as per mine, e.g. `IF(B5:B10000=DATEVALUE("1/1/2022")`.

Comment: tried something like this but no luck M2 is my date
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A5:A10000<>"",if(F5:F10000,"Japan",IF(G5:G10000<=M2,IF(H5:H10000>=M2,MATCH(A5:A10000,A5:A10000,0)))),ROW(A5:A10000)-MIN(ROW(A5:A10000))+1),1)))

Comment: `IF(F5:F10000,"Japan"` should be `IF(F5:F10000="Japan"`

Comment: AAAAHHHHHHHH yeahhh.. i was stuck with the idea of countifs... sorry. will try it..

Comment: still the same Error
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A5:A10000<>"",if(F5:F10000="Japan",IF(G5:G10000<=M2,IF(H5:H10000>=M2,MATCH(A5:A10000,A5:A10000,0)))),ROW(A5:A10000)-MIN(ROW(A5:A10000))+1),1)))

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. For every `IF` clause you include, you will need a closing parenthesis after the `MATCH` statement. `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A5:A10000<>"",IF(F5:F10000="Japan",IF(G5:G10000<=M2,IF(H5:H10000>=M2,MATCH(A5:A10000,A5:A10000,0))))),ROW(A5:A10000)-MIN(ROW(A5:A10000))+1),1))`

Comment: ohhw yeah.. im closing it on the last part of the formula. Its working now mate.. really awesome.. thank you so much!

Comment: will try to understand the formula deeply so i can use it more..